# Is it possible to create a new RabbitMQ queue from a proxy in WSO2 ESB that previously didn’t exist?

Tags: proxy, wso2, rabbitmq

We are using WSO2 with RabbitMQ in our project. One requirement is that the consumer of RabbitMQ should generate the queue in case it did not previously exist.

We make the following proxy (without creating the "queue" queue previously in the Rabbit broker):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="AMQPProxy3" startOnLoad="true" trace="enable" transports="rabbitmq" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <log level="full"/>
        <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
        <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="http://localhost:8080/greeting"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
</target>
<parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">queue</parameter>
<parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
</proxy>
```

The ESB throws the following exception:

> TID: [-1] [] [2017-08-25 13:23:06,139] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.ServiceTaskManager} -  Error, Connection already closed AMQPProxy3, Listner id - 302 {org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.ServiceTaskManager}
>   com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'queue' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)

In this case, the RabbitMQ consumer using the ESB does not create the queue in case it does not exist.

However, if we use a Java project that uses amqp-client-4.0.2.jar (Java library that gives us the official page of Rabbit) that consumer is able to create the queue.

```
package com.ing.rabbitmq;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

public class Send2 {

   private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "queue";

   public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

   ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
   factory.setHost("localhost");
   Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
   Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

   channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
   String message = "{\"id\":100,\"content\":\"Manolito\"}";
   channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
   System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");

   channel.close();
   connection.close();
  }
}
```

Could we get the ESB to create the queue just like if we used the java client (amqp-client-4.0.2.jar)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible with WSO2 ESB. 
Try setting out the following property in your proxy configuration.

```
<parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.autodeclare">true</parameter>
```

If that not works, please let me know the WSO2 ESB version you are using.

Comment: Thanks ECR. We are using the WSO2 5. We have tried adding these parameters: <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.autodeclare">true</parameter>
 <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.autodeclare">true</parameter> but we get the same result.